# Highligh bar menu when current site is open

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I am using dreamweaver to make my bar menu and wonder how to keep the highlight on bar when the page is open. Right now it only show the highlight when the pointer is over the bar.

Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(./SpryAssets/008912409_prevstill.png);
    text-align: center;
}
.HEADER {
    background: rgb(207,231,250, 0.8); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA    /Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9$
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(207,231,250,0.8) 0%,     rgba(99,147,193,0.8) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-    stop(0%,rgba(207,231,250,0.8)), color-stop(100%,rgba(99,147,193,1)))$
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(207,231,250,0.8)     0%,rgba(99,147,193,0.8) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(207,231,250,0.8) 0%,rgba(99,147,193,0.8)     100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(207,231,250,0.8) 0%,rgba(99,147,193,0.8)      100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(207,231,250,0.8)     0%,rgba(99,147,193,0.8) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cfe7fa',     endColorstr='#6393c1',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
 .HEADER p {
    font-size: 24px;
 }



</style>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="HEADER">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <div id="image"></div>
<style>
 p {
 white-space: pre;
}
 </style>
```

Code cont.

```
 <p> <span class="TitleArticle">Title</span></p>
 <div id="author">
    <p><span>authors</span></div>


</div>
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
 <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>  </li>
 <li><a href="article.html">ARTICLE</a>  </li>
<li><a href="#" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">GENE LISTS</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="chromremodgenes.html">Chromatin remodeling genes</a></li>
   <li><a href="dnarepgenes.html">DNA repair genes</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">CELL CYCLE</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="cc_chrommod.html">Chromatin remodeling</a></li>
     <li><a href="cc_dnarep.html">DNA repair genes</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="Methods.html">METHODS</a>  </li>
 <li><a href="Data.html">DATA</a>  </li>
 <li><a href="Fascility.html">FACILITY</a></li>
 <li><a href="Authors.html">AUTHORS</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: html and css please or a fiddle ?

Comment: you can add class .active for li on every page which you want the menu to be highlighted and add hover effect to that class

Comment: where do I add this?

Comment: in the menu bar of course

Comment: can you add hover class css also?